# Setinterval Overlap after Clearinterval JS

Tags: javascript

The story is a balloon that falls down. if you manage to click on the balloon('Stop' function) you win. otherwise, if it down 450px you lose.

The problem is when I press the balloon: its change the src, alert me and clearInterval - Now I thought that it will stop or wait for the next event.
but, after I click 'ok' on the alert its keep falling...

**My Code:**

```
function Start() {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
    document.getElementById("balon").style.left = num + 'px';
    var id = setInterval(function() {
        if (posX > 450 && ok) {
            alert("Looser");
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            posX += Vpos * dt;
            document.getElementById("balon").style.top = posX + 'px';
        }
    }, dt);
}

function Stop() {
    document.getElementById("balon").src = 'JS Pics/balon2.gif';
    alert("Winner");
    clearInterval(id);


}
```

In conclusion, I found some way to stop it by adding Bool variable. see below:
**Anyway, I am not sure why this happens(would be happy for explanation) or another way to fix this.** Thanx.

```
function Start() {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
    document.getElementById("balon").style.left = num + 'px';
    var id = setInterval(function() {
        if (posX > 450 && ok) {
            alert("Looser");
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            if (ok) {
                posX += Vpos * dt;
                document.getElementById("balon").style.top = posX + 'px';
            } else {
                clearInterval(id);
            }
        }
    }, dt);
}

function Stop() {
    ok = false;
    document.getElementById("balon").src = 'JS Pics/balon2.gif';
    alert("Winner");
    clearInterval(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` is in scope of `Start` function, so it's undefined in scope of `Stop` function.
 You can declare it outside both functions, so they could both access it:

```
var id;

function Start() {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
    document.getElementById("balon").style.left = num + 'px';
    id = setInterval(function () {
        if (posX > 450 && ok) {
            alert("Looser");
            clearInterval(id);
        }
        else {
                posX += Vpos * dt;
                document.getElementById("balon").style.top = posX + 'px';
        }
    }, dt);
}

function Stop() {
    document.getElementById("balon").src = 'JS Pics/balon2.gif';
    alert("Winner");
    clearInterval(id);
}
```

Your fix with `ok` works, because you don't declare it with keyword `var` so it's assigned to `window` object (or you have declared it in outer scope and forgot to append in code snippet).

Comment: Wonderfull! Thanx.